# how to get data from dynamically added text boxes in windows phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing one app. In this I want to get the data from text boxes which is added dynamically. Below is my code

```
for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
    {

        TextBox TxtBoxU = new TextBox() { Width = 30 };

        TextBox TxtBoxE = new TextBox() { Width = 20 };

        RadioButton radioButton1 = new RadioButton();


        RadioButton radioButton2 = new RadioButton();

        TextBlock tb1 = new TextBlock();
        TextBlock tb2 = new TextBlock();
        TextBlock tb3 = new TextBlock();

        TxtBoxU.Name = "TextBoxU" + i.ToString();
        TxtBoxE.Name = "TextBoxE" + i.ToString();


        tb1.FontSize = 20;
        tb2.FontSize = 20;
        tb3.FontSize = 20;

        tb1.Name = "tb1" + i.ToString();
        tb2.Name = "tb2" + i.ToString();
        tb3.Name = "tb3" + i.ToString();

        tb1.Text = "name " + (i + 1).ToString() + " : ";
        tb2.Text = "Age : ";
        tb3.Text = "Gender : ";
        radioButton1.Content = "Male";
        radioButton1.GroupName = "Gender";
        radioButton2.Content = "Female";
        radioButton2.GroupName = "Gender";

        MyStackPanel.Children.Add(tb1);
        MyStackPanel.Children.Add(TxtBoxU);

        MyStackPanel.Children.Add(tb2);
        MyStackPanel.Children.Add(TxtBoxE);

        MyStackPanel.Children.Add(tb3);
        MyStackPanel.Children.Add(radioButton1);
        MyStackPanel.Children.Add(radioButton2);

    }
```

In the above code I want to get the  text from TxtBoxU1 ,TxtBoxE1,TxtBoxU2,TxtBoxE2,......so on

how will I get the data from textboxes

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add them to a list and loop through when you need them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just iterate through the `MyStackPanel.Children` as it's a [regular collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.uielementcollection(v=vs.110).aspx) (implements [IEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx)).

```
        foreach (var child in MyStackPanel.Children)
        {
            if (!(child is TextBox))
            {
                continue;
            }
            var textbox = child as TextBox;
            if (textbox.Name == "TextBoxU1")
            {
                var text = textbox.Text; //whatever you want to do here
            }
        }
```

However I'd recommend you to read about [DataBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758320.aspx) and [MVVM pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/100175/Model-View-ViewModel-MVVM-Explained).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in several ways.

1. You can drill down using a `VisualTreeHelper`.
2. You could try the following too

   TextBox tb = MyStackPanel.Children[1] as TextBox;

Indexes are the same order as you entered.